# Python Pandas Dataframe.to_csv behaving differently than Saving as CSV within Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

A strange one really...Trying to load a csv onto an IBMi, just a standard csv file, when I use python pandas `.to_csv`, the file won't load, but if I import the same file into excel (using import), then save as `.csv` (used the UTF-8, csv and MSDOS csv - all work); the file loads; which suggests the `df.to_csv` is different to the standard excel `.csv` file.

Tried different encoding, but all the same problem, which suggests something else.

python code

```
if output_dir == '': output_dir = 'migration_output'
if not os.path.exists(output_dir) or not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    print('Output directory /' + output_dir + ' created')
    os.makedirs(output_dir) 
filename_timestamp = '_' + str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")) + '.csv'
IND_csv_df = pd.DataFrame(ind_output)
IND_csv_df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir + 'IND_' + str(filename_timestamp)),index=False, header=False)
```

csv file looks OK, loads OK in excel and notepad++

any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...sorted...its the line terminator, mac defaults to CR, windows to CRLF, and excel uses CRLF...so updated .to_csv to write CRLF and hey presto...worked.

line_terminator='\r\n'